# Is it possible to add views to deployed .NET MVC Razor site

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to add Razor views to a deployed .NET MVC site? How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSHTMLs are not binaries like controllers. Assuming the existing site is already set up to use Razor files then yes, you can drop them in there and they work as expected.

If you have to change controller/ action method code to actually use this view you would have to recompile and redeploy the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible but first build your project with adding new .cshtml file and then adds on specific folder where you want on deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I will say yes.

In asp.net, there are 2 different build. Project build and dynamic build.

Project build is the normal build u see on other types of build. Generating doll or exe.

Dynamic build is the build when for cshtml related files. It is built by triggering it. So, ideally, u can replace cshtml or add cshtml. And it will work for the iis.

Hope this answered your question.